# Should I use http.Error directly or return error in the http handler function?

Tags: go, http, web, error-handling

I am writing a web system, and am a bit confused about the http error handling code.

I've read the article [Error handling and Go](https://go.dev/blog/error-handling-and-go), in which errors are handled like this:

```golang
type appError struct{
    err error
    msg string
    code int
}

func MyHandleFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) *appError {
    err := ...
    if err != nil {
        return &appError{err, "Some error message", http.StatusInternalServerError}
    }
    
    ...
}

func (fn appHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if e := fn(w, r); e != nil { // e is *appError, not os.Error.
        c := appengine.NewContext(r)
        c.Errorf("%v", e.Error)
        http.Error(w, e.Message, e.Code)
    }
}
```

And here's my code before reading the article

```golang
func MyHandleFunc(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    err := ...
    if err != nil {
        httpError("Some error message", err, w, http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    ...
}

func httpError(msg string, err error, w http.ResponseWriter, code int){
    log.Printf("Error: %s\n%s", msg, err.Error())
    http.Error(w, msg, code)
}
```

Seems like both of them could reduce the repetitive code, but I'm not sure which is better.

Comment: There is no single right or wrong here.